# scaffold .NET Core instance failure

Tags: asp.net-core, scaffolding

I do example from this
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-highlight-selected-row-in-ngfor-in-angular-9/
I build my own database EmployeeManager

dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=contactmanager;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Model --project EmployeeManager

But I get

> Build started... Build succeeded. To protect potentially sensitive
> information in your connection string, you should move it out of
> source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using
> the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on
> storing connection strings, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Instance failure.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
> SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
> Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
> integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod
> authType)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
> withFailover)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
> SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
> timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool
> pool)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(DbConnection connection, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas,
> IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1
> schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluarlize)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Instance failure.

Why?

Comment: Make sure the database `contactmanager` exists.